# How to get an ItemsSource to refresh its bind?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding

I've got a view which shows a listbox that is bound to **GetAll()**:

```
<DockPanel>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding GetAll}"
             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource allCustomersDataTemplate}"
             Style="{StaticResource allCustomersListBox}">
    </ListBox>
</DockPanel>
```

**GetAll() is an ObservableCollection property** in my ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<Customer> GetAll
{
    get
    {
        return Customer.GetAll();
    }
}
```

which in turn **calls a GetAll() model method** which reads an XML file to fill the ObservableCollection.:

```
public static ObservableCollection<Customer> GetAll()
{
    ObservableCollection<Customer> customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();

    XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(Customer.GetXmlFilePathAndFileName());
    var customerObjects = from customer in xmlDoc.Descendants("customer")
                          select new Customer
                          {
                              Id = (int)customer.Element("id"),
                              FirstName = customer.Element("firstName").Value,
                              LastName = customer.Element("lastName").Value,
                              Age = (int)customer.Element("age")
                          };
    foreach (var customerObject in customerObjects)
    {
        Customer customer = new Customer();

        customer.Id = customerObject.Id;
        customer.FirstName = customerObject.FirstName;
        customer.LastName = customerObject.LastName;
        customer.Age = customerObject.Age;

        customers.Add(customer);
    }

    return customers;
}
```

This all works fine EXCEPT when the user goes to another view, **edits the XML file** and comes back to this view where ***the old data is still showing***.

**How can I tell this view to "refresh its bindings" so that it shows the actual data.**

It feels like I am going about WPF here with too much of an HTML/HTTP metaphor, I sense there is a more natural way to get ObservableCollection to update itself, hence its name, but this is the only way I can get the user to be able to edit data in a WPF application at the moment. So help on any level is appreciated here.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

An `ItemsControl` requests its binding once and caches the reference thereafter.

If the content of the collection object are modified, and it implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` (as `ObservableCollection` does), it will pick up any added or removed object.

Now, if you want the binding to supply a new collection object to the `ListBox`, you can have your view-model implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise `PropertyChanged`, passing in `GetAll` as the property name.
This will have the effect of warning the binding that the property value has changed (there is a new `ObservableCollection` ready to be picked up), which it will supply to the `ListBox`, which will re-generate its items.

So as long as you effect changes from your app, working on the `ObservableCollection` returned by `GetAll`, you can add and remove and the list will stay in synch. When you want to pick up external modifications (you might have a refresh button somewhere, or a natural point where it makes sense to reload the whole file), you can have your view-model raise the `PropertyChanged` event, which will automatically call the property getter, which will call the static method, which will return a fresh new collection.

Nitpicker note: why do you give method names to properties?

Comment: I changed GetAll() to GetAll, thanks. The problem is that I have two views which each get a separate GetAll ObservableCollection from their respective ViewModels and when one ObservableCollection changes, the other one doesn't change. Do I need to store these globally somewhere?

Comment: If both views are supposed to be synchronized during edition, then yes, you need to somehow share the same object. 
In your case, there could be a Data Access system that loads and caches the collection, and each ViewModel would then request the current collection. That way they both are aware of each other's modification.
Now if you need to reload the collection from the file, you would have a way to warn every viewmodel that the collection object has changed, so that they can raise their PropertyChanged event once they have obtained the new reference.

Comment: So for now my solution as to refresh the DataSource every time the user control (view) is loaded, works great, thanks!

Comment: Sure would be nice to know where this is cached.  (I have an issue where the cache is updating when it should not.)  Feel like updating with that bit of info?

Comment: Make sure add Two way binding to the List

Answer (score 11):

Below line work same as when we remove to add object in collection:

```
CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(CustomObservableCollection).Refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep a reference to your `ObservableCollection` and the XML file's last-modified time as of the time you loaded it. Whenever the window gets focus, check the timestamp on the disk file. If it's changed, clear and re-populate the `ObservableCollection`. The GUI is automatically listening for change events from the `ObservableCollection` and will re-populate automatically when you modify the collection's contents.