# Changes in combobox' itemssource not passed to binding of selectedvalue

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have some troubles with this scenario:

```
ComboBox cb = new ComboBox cb;
cb.ItemsSource = listItems; //ObservableCollection, contains objects with DependencyProperty "Name"
cb.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
cb.SelectedValuePath = "Name";
Binding b = new Binding("NameOfItem");
b.Source = myObject;  //Has DependencyProperty "NameOfItem"
b.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
cb.SetBinding(ComboBox.SelectedValueProperty, b);
```

When I select another value in the combobox, the bounded source "myobject" gets updated.
But when I just change the name of an item in the ItemsSource, the displayed value in the comboBox gets updated indeed, but "myObject" gets no notification, not until I reselect the item in the comboBox.

Comment: What do you mean by `"myObject" gets no notification`? The `NameOfItem` property not being updated?

Comment: Why it should be if you only update a property of that object. I mean you update `NameOfItem.Name`, not `NameOfItem` itself. If you want to receive notifications about updating its properties you should subscribe to `PropertyChanged` event of that object.

Comment: NameOfItem is just a string. And if the selectedvalue of the combobox changes, I want this string to be updated. This works, when I select another value, but not when the selectedvalue changes due to changes in the itemssource without selecting another value in the combobox.

Comment: In your scenario the selected value is not changing as you are changing the property of item but not item. I think you need to specify the path while defining the binding.

Answer (score 0):

Put your collection in ObservableCollection<> and bind your combobox to it.

```
ObservableCollection obc = new ObservableCollection(listItems);
```

[Read common mistakes while using ObservableCollection](http://updatecontrols.net/doc/tips/common_mistakes_observablecollection)

Comment: look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806714/how-to-get-an-itemssource-to-refresh-its-bind

Comment: Thanks for the links, but that is not the problem. As already mentioned in the question, the combobox itself and the selectedvalue gets updated, but not the object, that is bound to selectedvalue.