# Combobox is not refreshing in WPF using MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, combobox, refresh

I have a problem similar to [How to get an ItemsSource to refresh its bind?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806714/how-to-get-an-itemssource-to-refresh-its-bind)

But I did used the INotifyPropertyChange interface and still having the issue. Here is the XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Sample.Module.Pages.View.ModifyDataTypeView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
         xmlns:Dialog="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sample.Module.Pages.ViewModel"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="500" d:DesignWidth="350">
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:DataTypeViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
<Canvas>
        <ComboBox Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" 
                  Margin="13,22,0,0"
                  Style="{DynamicResource VirtualisedMetroComboBox}"
                  Controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Autocompletion"
                  DisplayMemberPath="DataTypeName"
                  IsEditable="True"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding DataTypes}"
                  MaxDropDownHeight="125"
               SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedDataType, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="25"/>
        </Canvas>
```

Here is the ViewModel:

```
 public class DataTypeViewModel : DomainObject
{
    private ObservableCollection<DataTypeRepository> dataTypes;
    private DataTypeRepository selectedDataType;
    private DataTypeModel dataTypeModel;

    public DataTypeViewModel()
    {
        dataTypeModel = new DataTypeModel();
        selectedDataType = new DataTypeRepository();
        this.dataTypes = dataTypeModel.GetAllDataTypes();
        InsertDataTypeCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnInsertDataType);
    }
    public ObservableCollection<DataTypeRepository> DataTypes 
    { 
        get { return dataTypes; }
        set 
        {
            if (!EqualityComparer<ObservableCollection<DataTypeRepository>>.Default.Equals(dataTypes,value))
            {
                dataTypes = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("DataTypes");
            }
        }
    }

    public DataTypeRepository SelectedDataType
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedDataType;
        }
        set
        {
            if (!EqualityComparer<DataTypeRepository>.Default.Equals(selectedDataType, value))
            {
                selectedDataType = value;
                InsertDataTypeCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedDataType");
            }
        }
    }
    public DelegateCommand InsertDataTypeCommand { get; private set; }
    private void OnInsertDataType()
    {
        DataBaseOperationStatusMessage = dataTypeModel.InsertDataType(selectedDataType);
        DatabaseOperationComplete = true;
        DataTypes = dataTypeModel.GetAllDataTypes();
    }
}
```

Please note the InsertDataTypeCommand command is used in another another tab of the app where the "DataType" is added. After adding a DataType user clicks to the Modify Tab to see the new DataType in the combobox list. But that is not happenning. If you restart the app and go to the Modify page you can see the new record.
The issue is the Combobox is not getting updated even when am using INotifyPropertyChange.

What am I missing here?

Comment: ObservableCollection<T> properties should be read only.  There's absolutely no need to expose them using INPC-enabled properties.  If you want do add/remove items from the collection, simply use the normal collection methods.  This might have something to do with your problem.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. So you suggest to change the property of ObservableCollection<T> to List<T>?
I did that with no effect.

Comment: Where... how... Who.... I said ***what???***  Lemme read my comment again...  Hmm, properties should be read-only, yeah...  No need, INPC, okay... Use normal collection methods, uh huh.... I believe the issue here is that you're high.  Please pass the bowl.

Comment: Am trying to solve a issue here and seeking help. If you find that funny, go ahead and laugh elsewhere.

Comment: Try reading my comment and doing what it suggests.  Try not doing what it doesn't suggest.  It might help you.

Comment: This was my earlier code, -
'public ObservableCollection<DataTypeRepository> DataTypes { get { return dataTypes; } private set { }}
private void OnInsertDataType()
    {
        DataBaseOperationStatusMessage = dataTypeModel.InsertDataType(selectedDataType);
        DatabaseOperationComplete = true;
        dataTypes = dataTypeModel.GetAllDataTypes();
    }'
I was updating the private variable. It did not work.

Comment: Updating a private ObservableCollection variable that is exposed as a public property is fine, as the binding is watching the collection for INotifyCollectionChanged events.  The opposite is true for INotifyPropertyChanged properties.  As to *why* it isn't working... What I normally do when a binding is not working as expected, I grab Snoop and examine the binding at runtime.  It will show binding errors that can help you find a solution.  I don't see anything striking in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your binding to include the update trigger...

```
SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedDataType, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Comment: actually the issue is not updating the collection, i.e. DataTypes; not the selection.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the following line isn't causing the collection to be updated:

```
 DataTypes = dataTypeModel.GetAllDataTypes();
```

From your code it looks like you go and insert the new item into your database or wherever, and are then running the method that loads all the items from the database. Instead of running that method it would be better, when you are inserting into the database, to create a corresponding DataTypeRepository item and add that to the collection.

```
this.DataTypes.Add(new DataTypeRepository { property1= "somedata"});
```

It just means if you're adding a new item onto what could be a huge list of items, you won't have to reload everything.

You should probably also update your itemsource to be 2 way binding (unless you're doing the readonly that Will suggested in the comments) and put the updatetrigger to property changed (by default its on focus lost i think)